# Accessing Raspberry Pi Hotspot via VNC

Tags: wifi, remote, vnc, hotspot

I have a headless Raspberry Pi 4 that I want to connect to via VNC in the absence of an external wifi or ethernet network. The Pi is being used as an antenna controller far away from civilisation, which is why there is no available wifi or ethernet.

I can set up the Pi to provide a local wifi hotspot and can connect to that network via a computer. But I don't know the IP address to connect to via VNC. I presume it is possible to access the Pi using VNC via the Pi's own hotspot.

Does anyone know what IP address the Pi uses in this situation?

Is there a way to configure this before hand?

Comment: Doesn't the pi use whatever IP address **you configure it to use** when you configure the Pi as a *wifi hotspot*?

Comment: `nmap` comes to mind. Or pinging to the broadcast address.

Comment: Configure dnsmasq with a know IP address and a known DHCP range. Then you'll known what you're getting when you connect.

Comment: Thanks for the comments but I admit to being a novice when it comes to the details of these connections. The comment "Doesn't the pi use whatever IP address ** you configure it to use ** " is not helpful" . I can configure the pi as a hotspot by going to the wifi icon, clicking advanced options, then clicking create a wifi hotspot. There is no option for setting up an IP address, which suggests that this is done automatically somewhere (or nowhere).

Comment: I can connect an external computer to the Pi wifi via its broadcast SSID but still don't know how to actually communicate with the Pi itself. I know this is possible but not sure how. Since I don't know its IP address how do I ping it? All I have is the wifi SSID, since that is what is broadcast.

Comment: The IP address used is `raspberrypi`, so there is no need for IPs.

Comment: Thanks for your help but that doesn't work either. The host is unresolvable. However, I did find that by pinging a "random" address, in my case 198.0.0.1 I got the message "92 bytes from 10.42.0.1: Destination Net Unreachable" which tells me the IP address I needed was 10.42.0.1 (!!)

Comment: I discovered that using an IP address raspberrypi:local worked :-)